# ¿Cómo validar el tipo de entrada en C?

Tags: c

Tengo un programa que pide datos datos al usuario, pero si agregas `" | #$&#$&& !!"#!23 " etc..` con símbolos raros, el programa no valida que pases un int o un float.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa eso? Y ¿cómo podría agregar algún tipo de condicional que permita verificar si los datos introducidos son correctos?

Mi código actual:

```
#include<stdio.h>//libreria


int main(){

    int a;
    float b;
    char c;


    printf("digite el valor de la variable A : ");
    scanf("%i",&a);
    printf(" el valor de la variable B : ");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("el valor es : %i",a);
    printf("el valor es : %f",b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ A que te refieres con lo de `agregarle un if else` ?

Comment: estaba pensando que en momento de que el usuario ingrese el dato se valide con un if y valide que fue un int y igualmente en el float, algo asi estaba pensando.

Comment: igualmente en el char

Answer (score 3):

Hola aquí te dejo un pequeño código para un ejemplo con un valor entero. El código verifica que el número de parámetros correctos introducidos por consola es 1 ya que `scanf` devuelve el número de parámetros correctos introducidos. En ese caso imprime `valid integer` En caso contrario imprime `failure`.

```
int num;
if(scanf("%i", &num) != 1)
    printf("failure\n");
else
    printf("valid integer");
```

Una adaptación de tu código podría ser:

```
#include<stdio.h>//libreria

int main(){

    int a;
    float b;
    char c;

    // variable A
    printf("digite el valor de la variable A : ");
    if(scanf("%i", &a) != 1)
        printf("Entero no válido\n");
    else
        printf(" el valor es: %i\n",a);

    // variable B
    printf("digite el valor de la variable B : ");
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    if(scanf("%f", &b) != 1)
        printf("Valor con coma flotante no válido\n");
    else
        printf(" el valor de la variable B es: %f\n",b);

    // variable C
    printf("digite el valor de la variable C : ");

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    if(scanf("%c", &c) != 1)
        printf("Valor caracter no válido\n");
    else
        printf(" el valor de la variable C es: %c\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Por último, he añadido un fragmento de código que borra del escaner los enter introducidos en el scaner para poder verificar la entrada de los siguientes registros sin que la aplicación salte al siguiente elemento.

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Puedes ejecutar el código aquí: https://onlinegdb.com/ryfe798Gb

Comment: En el primer fragmento de código, si el usuario introduce abcde lo que se imprimirá por pantalla es failure

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60114/discussion-between-hector-and-trauma).